# How do I aligned text with something and keep that text where it is no matter the screen size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want the text "social" to stay where it is, vertically aligned with the black bars. But as you can see when I put it into bootstrap/html it is not aligned BUT atleast it stays with the black bars.
[on normal devices and mobiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIoTp.png)

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L2Lw.png).

When I do fix this by adding in css it is perfectly aligned to the black bars but it doesnt stay where it is when the screen gets smaller(mobile).

[on normal screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciQlP.png)

[on mobile screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hnXT.png)

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4hcM.png)

[css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWURW.png)

I want this to be perfectly aligned and stay aligned even when screen sizes change.

Comment: Need a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ~ Code

Comment: Avoid posting your code, output, or errors in images, post it in a text format instead!

Answer (score 0):

you should detect the screen width in your css.
The code could be like this:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
 #socials {
    max-width: 540px;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #socials {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #socials {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #socials {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using fixed as position instead of absolute,

```
#socials
{
    position:fixed;
}
```